# MySQL Permissions for CRON job

Tags: php, mysql, cron, mysql-error-1142

I have written a PHP script to be executed by CRON on a daily basis to clean files and remove old database entries..

The script has no problems being run, so I know its not a CRON issue.

The problem is that I get the following error:

> **Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'username'@'localhost' for table 'users' in **/cron_removeOld.php** on line **35**

I am using the same DB credentials for the backend admin users, so I know they have SELECT privileges.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the script being run outside of the webserver?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cron:

```
20 0 * * * php -q /home/user/public_html/tssol/contract/admin/cron_removeOld.php
```

PHP (Line 35):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT idusers, contract FROM users WHERE contractExpireDate <= NOW()");
```

The db creds are in an include file that is shared with other pages so I know thats not an issue..will post if you think it will help

Comment: post your cron code & php source code

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that query.  It _must_ be a permission issue.

Comment: @Jonah, any ideas?? I've been at this all day.  The downfall is we are on a shared host so I have no root access to the server

Comment: Is the web server, the db server and the server executing the cronjob the same machine?

Comment: @Emil, I have no clue.  Its a shared hosting server, and I don't know.  The guy who put us on this host is contacting the hosting company to see if they have any input.  For host in the DB connection I have tried localhost, and set it to 127.0.0.1 to see what happens tonight....

Comment: Personally, I would flee from any shared host who puts the database on the same machine as the web server. But wait for the answer from the hosting company - I don't think anybody can help you until we get some more information about the environment.

Comment: @guyfromfl: are you sure you selected the correct database?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL permission **has nothing to do** with PHP executed by CLI or whatever.
Check if your mysql user has the SELECT provileges for users table

Comment: I'm 100% sure it does. The MySQL user is the same user I use to manage the records in the backend, it has SELECT INSERT DELETE UPDATE privs